# JQuery SerialScroll Tabs bottom-border Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have implemented the SerialScroll which is similar to Scrollable Tabs:

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/WvpcR/

I would like to somehow eliminate the small bottom-borders that are in between each tab that show up onload:

[image]

The reason why you don't see the bottom-border all the way across, and directly below the Tabs is because each .navigations li bottom-border is initially set to -1:

```
#mid-featureleft-client .navigations li{
float: left;
margin:0 3px -1px 0;
position: relative;
}
```

The click function then enables the bottom-border to appear below those Tabs which are not selected:

[image]

The best solution would be to have the 1st tab always selected upon load or within the Init Function, and then have the bottom-border appear all the way across the bottoms of those Tabs which are not selected.

Does anyone have an idea about how I could implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve for your problem, you should set margin-bottom value to 0 in the css class here.

```
#mid-featureleft-client .navigations li{
float: left;
margin:0 3px 0 0;
position: relative;
}
```

than, you should add "margin-bottom:-1px" to the white class.

```
.white {   
    border-top: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
    border-left: 1px solid #C6C6C6;    
    border-right: 1px solid #C6C6C6;    
    background-color: #F7F7F7; 
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WvpcR/25/

Comment: @sinanakyzaici I think I tried that one previously, but for some reason it looked a little strange having the bottom-border all the way across on-load.  So I just stuck with my original version, and you can barely even see those pieces of border in between the Tabs on the development site.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are "tabs", the first one should always be selected.

jQuery tabs has the first tab always selected.  Same is true for nearly every tab scenario.

Comment: this is not JQuery Tabs- I indicated its SerialScroll!